# Stacking rectangles to take as little space as possible

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a program that will calculate the minimal area taken by fitting rectangles together.

Input: Rectangles of different height and width.
Output: One rectangle that contains all these rectangles.
Rules: One cannot turn or roll the rectangles around and they cannot overlap.

I understand that this is related or is possibly defined as a bin packing problem (NP-hard). However the algorithms i found for those often set a limit on for example width. I have no such limits, the only goal is to get the resulting area as small as possible.

Any pointers on what algorithm is appropriate to get a decent solution?

Comment: Anyone else smell a homework problem?

Comment: Nah, this is pretty common in games, it's called texture packing.

Comment: Actually I'm automating a conversion of icons and images to a css sprite and I want the result to be as good as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www-rcf.usc.edu/~skoenig/icaps/icaps04/icapspapers/ICAPS04KorfR.pdf

Apparently this problem is harder than it looks at first. It's an interesting algorithm, since first it guesses a solution and then improves on it, so if you don't want to wait for the optimal solution, you can just run it for a set number of iterations to get an approximate solution (the longer you run it, the better the approximation).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I had bookmarked that some time ago to set aside for reading.  Now I got to finally read it.

Comment: That link no longer works. It can still be read from wayback machine however: https://web.archive.org/web/20040717141901/http://www-rcf.usc.edu/~skoenig/icaps/icaps04/icapspapers/ICAPS04KorfR.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend starting with a simple greedy approach, and seeing if that is good enough for your needs.  If your input is well-behaved or small, that may be all you need--and the complexity will go up quickly when you try to do something more sophisticated.

For example:  sort the rectangles by size, largest first.  Add the rectangles one at a time, trying each possible position for the new rectangle.  Pick the position that results in the smallest bounding box.

Another greedy approach would be to pick a starting rectangle, then repeatedly add the rectangle which results in the most dense arrangement (where density is defined as the percentage of the bounding box's area that is filled).

Comment: I was going to suggest those two as well, but having worked on different NP problems with an initial assumption on "good" heuristic led me to experiment with what I thought would be "bad" heuristics. The results were surprising. Local minima and maxima situations occur. But I like your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by skimming through http://mathworld.wolfram.com - they're awesome for stuff like this.

Second, I could envision a dopey algorithm that would put the longest (in the X dimension) box on the bottom, then the tallest (in the Y dimension) on top of it on one side or the other. Then continue stacking them in this "stair-stepped" fashion going right wards and upwards (for example go right until you can't, then go up, etc, etc).

That's probably non-ideal, and may very well give you bad results, but it's what popped to mind first.