# Get the best square like arrangement

Tags: javascript, logic

### The Situation

I have a certain amount of squares. I want these square to always from a square like grid but it can't have any empty spaces. I'd use JavaScript to do this. The grid would be stored like so

```
var gridLayout = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
```

This would result in this grid

[image: 2 by 2 grid]

### The Problem

If I have 16 squares it would result with

```
var gridLayout = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15, 16]];
```

And the visual

[image: 4 by 4 grid]

Now all that's easy to do, but what if there's 3 squares? I'd like it to do something like this, favoring the **horizontal over the vertical layout**.

```
var gridLayout = [[1, 2, 3]];
```

with the visual

[image: 1 by 3 grid]

If I had 8 squares it couldn't make the perfect square so I'd like to be

```
var gridLayout = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]];
```

And the visual

[image: 2 by 4 grid]

### What I've tried

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339939/stacking-rectangles-to-into-the-most-square-like-arrangement-possible) but it seems to be working with rectangles instead of squares. I also have a very hard time following without the visuals of what they want.

I have also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251488/stacking-rectangles-to-take-as-little-space-as-possible?noredirect=1&lq=1) which is kinda similar but seem to be a bit irrelevant to my situation.

### Conclusion

How would I create the `gridLayout` in such a way as what I want? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you always want as many columns as elements in the subarrays and as many rows as elements in the array. This should be possible very easily with CSS grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ . Or is the problem generating the arrays?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: I don't know about the graphical part, but this seems straightforward enough. You have an array of *rows* (first level), each row being composed of *cells* (second level). I'm not sure what logic issue you have with that.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the link. But yes, I am having the issue with generating the arrays.

Comment: It wasn't clear from your post that this is part of your question.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry, edited.

Comment: A starting point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks. Choose a chunk size that divides the number of elements evenly. Then change the chunk size to get the right number of rows (which atm I'm not sure how to determine, e.g. should columns be always be larger or equal than rows? If so choose a chunk size where `#elements / chunk_size < chunk_size`). *edit:* Maybe choose `chunk_size` such that `chunk_size > Math.sqrt(#elements) && #elements % chunk_size === 0`

Comment: if the number of elements is a prime number you'll always have to use a single row. Is that OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a solution from [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks), to split an array of elements. Now we just need to determine the correct chunk size.

It looks like the criteria is:

- Each chunk must be the same size. This can be achieved by requiring that the number of elements is evenly divisible by the chunk size (i.e. `#elements % chunk_size === 0`).
- There should be at most as many rows as columns. In other words, the chunk size must be larger than the number of chunks. We can fulfill that by starting with a chunk size that is at least `Math.sqrt(#elements)`.

```js
// Implementation

function chunk (arr, len) {
  var chunks = [],
      i = 0,
      n = arr.length;

  while (i < n) {
    chunks.push(arr.slice(i, i += len));
  }

  return chunks;
}

function gridify(arr) {
  let size = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(arr.length));
  while (arr.length % size !== 0) {
    size += 1;
  }
  return chunk(arr, size);
}

// Helper functions for example

function range(n) {
   return Array.from({length: n}, (_,i) => i+1);
}

function run(size) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(gridify(range(size))));
}

// Create examples

run(4);
run(16);
run(3);
run(8);
```

There is hopefully a better way to determine the chunk size than just iterating and increasing size, but that's what I came with in this short time.

Comment: Another way to express the problem is: Find the smallest factor of `#elements` that is `> Math.sqrt(#elements)`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. Is there reason for multiple functions?

Comment: No. I just copied `chunk` from the other question.