# how to copy files to users home directory or current directory using distutils?

Tags: python, distutils

I am writing a python package (svnplot). I want to copy a shell script or batch files in users home directory or current directory, so that user can conveniently execute the commands in the package.

Currently to execute svnplot command, user have to call something similar to

python /svnplot/svnplot.py

If I copy a shell script or batch file in users home directory, then user just have to call

svnplot.sh

However, I am not able to figure out how to copy the files to users home directory.

Comment: Do you mean you want an install script or something similar? Because otherwise its just a copy-and-paste in your file browser. More details please.

Comment: i already have a basic setup script which installs svnplot in python site-packages folder. However, after installation, if you to run the svnplot then you have to give the full path of svnplot.py file. Hence I want to create a shell script, batchfile or another python script file which will be executed from user's home directory. 
I am not sure what you mean by 'its just a copy-and-pate' in your file brower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [distutils `scripts` option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/251488/4279) or [`entry_points/console_scripts` in setuptools](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html).

If there is a single main command then you could use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), py2exe to pack your package into a single executable. In simple cases it might be enough just to zip the package and execute that.